# Call row 10 to 20 in decended order

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using PDO. I need to call data from row 10 to 20 after it's sorted using DESC? How can I do this?

```
$sql = "SELECT item, price, availability 
         FROM items 
           WHERE category = :category 
             ORDER BY item DESC";
$stmt= $connect->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':category'=>"fruits"));
$rslt = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($rslt as $val){
  $data[] = $val; 
}
```

Comment: Removed comments and posted as an answer to resolve all issues future visitors may encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess I will post this as an answer because my comments I guess arose some confusion and there was a typo (quote and link had no error).

Mysql has a function called `limit`, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html.

per the documentation

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using prepared statements). With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return.

So to return rows 10 through 20 you can add

> limit 9,11

to the end of your query.

Per your code:

```
$sql = "SELECT item, price, availability 
        FROM items 
        WHERE category = :category 
        ORDER BY item DESC
        limit 9, 11";
$stmt= $connect->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':category'=>"fruits"));
$rslt = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
foreach ($rslt as $val){
    $data[] = $val; 
}
```

Note the `11` after the `9` this is because we want to start at row 10 and return 11 rows (e.g. 10-20).

Answer (score 0):

Update your sql.

`SELECT item, price, availability 
         FROM items 
           WHERE category = :category 
             ORDER BY item DESC limit 9,10`

Comment: He told 9,19 and I mentioned 9,10. Because by his query you will get 20 rows.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with posting your answer even if someone has already given another `"answer"` in comments. And this answer's premise is right as well. That comment is not a right answer, That gives you 20 rows when you ask for 10.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky To me the answer in the comments area looked as he certainly knew how to go about this but with probably a typo.

Comment: Even then, it does not take away someone else's right to be able to post an answer. Certainly doesn't make them deserve a down-vote just for that reason.